# Time series forecasting in Python with 2 categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, regression, forecasting

What approach is the best for a time series forecasting where you want to include 2 categorical variables in python? Im not finding any useful information that can help guide me with this; mainly everything I've found is about numerical variables only (both independent and independent variables)

My data looks like this: [image: data]

Basically I have 10 years (2010-910) of the medium salary data, per county (42) per field of activity (19). I am looking for guidance to get predictions for next years. As in - what would be the medium salary for a hotel agent in 2020 in X county?

Any ideas? I am a newby in ptyhon so I could use some code as well, thanks in advance

Comment: You would first need to convert your categorical variables to numerical ones by encoding them (e.g. one-hot encoding), you can then use the features as you would with numerical features.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your data, maybe give some examples per text. Do not just ask for code, this site is not a code-writing service.